# Handle add new feature event and/or access feature before commit?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

Is it possible with PyQGIS to catch "add new feature" event before commiting changes on the layer? or at least to access new features before commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `QgsVectorLayer` has quite a number of signals that will may suite your needs. Documentation for [1.8](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsVectorLayer.html#signals) and [master](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#signals) on these links.

Note there are minor changes to the API between 1.8 and master, and it appears that the python bindings have a few issues that are still [unresolved](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6573).

This sample code defines a couple of listeners, then attaches them to a memory layer.  If you start editing the layer you will see each signal triggers a line in the message log.

This code is (mostly) compatible with 1.8 and master and is intended to be pasted into the python console.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def logLayerModified( onlyGeometry = None ):
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage( "layer modified" )
    QApplication.beep()

def logFeatureAdded(fid):
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage( "feature added, id = " + str(fid) )
    QApplication.beep() 

def logEditingStarted():
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage( "editing started" )
    QApplication.beep() 

def logCommittedFeaturesAdded( layerId, addedFeatures ):
    message = layerId + " has features added: "
    for feature in addedFeatures:
        message += str( feature.id() ) + ", "
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage( message )
    QApplication.beep()         

layer = QgsVectorLayer( "Point", "Layer Signal Demo", "memory" )    
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers( [layer] )

layer.layerModified.connect( logLayerModified )
layer.featureAdded.connect( logFeatureAdded )
layer.editingStarted.connect( logEditingStarted )
layer.committedFeaturesAdded.connect( logCommittedFeaturesAdded )
```

**EDIT:**
Even with an incomplete set of signals you can probably get the access you require by performing you own analysis.

I have a naive implementation here that will slow down for large feature counts. Depending on your needs you may be able to optimize by reducing the amount of data being handled during the cross referencing. You may get speed gains by omitting the geometry or full attribute table from the query until you have identified the features you are interested in.

Note that this is designed for 1.8, feature iteration has [changed](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2013-February/024278.html) significantly for master.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def layerModified( onlyGeometry = None ):
    global establishedFeatureIds
    newFeatureIds = []
    layer.select()
    feature = QgsFeature()
    while layer.nextFeature( feature ):
        id = feature.id()
        if not id in  establishedFeatureIds:
            newFeatureIds.append( id )
    message = "New features: "
    for id in newFeatureIds:
        message += str(id) + ", "
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage( message )

def editingStarted():
    global establishedFeatureIds
    establishedFeatureIds = []
    layer.select()
    feature = QgsFeature()
    while layer.nextFeature( feature ):
        establishedFeatureIds.append( feature.id() )

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
if layer is None:
    layer = QgsVectorLayer( "Point", "Cross-reference Demo", "memory" )    
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers( [layer] )

layer.layerModified.connect( layerModified )
layer.editingStarted.connect( editingStarted )
```

Comment: Hi Kelly, 
I forgot to mention that I'm using PostgreSQL layer and I tried to handle `featureAdded` signal with no luck.
`QObject.connect(layer, SIGNAL("featureAdded(qint64)"), self.featureAdded)`.

However, `editingStarted` and `editingStopped` work ok. So, I'm looking for any solution either to catch featureAdded event or at least to have an access to the new features before commit.

Comment: Which QGIS version are you targeting?

Comment: It is 1.8, but think to switch on 1.9 since there are some bugs fixed in the latest build.

Comment: I did some tests and yes, `featureAdded` doesn't work for  memory and postgres layers in 1.8 and master. However, thank you for the clue, so I can at least find new features now.  Unfortunately it is not very effective with big layers, as you noted. It would be nice if it is possible to pick up all changed features from provider or elsewhere, including new, modified and deleted...

Comment: I'm confused now which version I should proceed with, since if I go with 1.8 it will not work with 2.0 later on.  Is there any source with the latest PyQGIS API documentation on the Internet (not for 1.8)?

Comment: The "master" link I included above is for the nightly build.  The cookbook has not been updated yet.  Regarding master I believe that a feature freeze is due this month, at that point the API should be stable allowing you to develop your plugin in parallel to the QGIS team as they apply a bit of polish in the lead up to an official release. Depending on how quickly your users will adopt 2.0, I would recommend moving forward and targeting the latest API.  However if you are targeting a user-base that will not upgrade for sometime then I guess your hands are tied.

Comment: Thanks for guidance Kelly. It is new application for the users, so looks like I should definitely continue with 2.0, however the only problem is that I don't know when 2.0 can be released, while I need to deliver the final version after 2 months.

Comment: @KellyThomas I'm trying to adapt your first code snippet to my plugin, but am wondering how to fulfill the fid parameter for logFeatureAdded(fid). This worked just fine, as you said, in the python console, but am getting a TypeError (not enough arguments) when calling it from my feature form python logic code.