# QGIS - how to retrieve information on features during editing

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt

I am developing a QGIS plugin that allows me to draw QgsPoints on a vector layer. When drawing, I toggle QGIS's edit mode.
In some cases, the last drawn point needs to be deleted. In order to do this, I need to retrieve the feature id of the last drawn feature *while the edit mode is toggled*.

Unhappily, I am unable to do so. I've been searching for a solution and found nothing so far :

- I can [iterate on the layer features](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html), but the features
  coordinates are empty as long as edit mode is toggled.
- I can [connect
  to the adding features signal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53269/handle-add-new-feature-event-and-or-access-feature-before-commit), but again, the signal is sent only
  when the edit mode is deactivated.

In order to draw, I've developed a FeatureDrawingPoint class, inheriting from QgsMapTool. I draw on a QgsRubberBand that does not give me any access to the ID of the feature I'm drawing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to find the id of the last added feature using pyQGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102376/how-to-find-the-id-of-the-last-added-feature-using-pyqgis)

Comment: No problem! Glad you got your problem solved =)

Answer (score 0):

This post is a duplicate to this post :  [How to find the id of the last added feature using pyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102376/how-to-find-the-id-of-the-last-added-feature-using-pyqgis)

The answer is the exact same one. Very sorry!